# CakePHP 3 patchEntity SQL date fails

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an array like this:

```
['valid_from' => '2016-02-01']
```

In my model I have the following validation rule

```
$validator->date('valid_from')->allowEmpty('valid_from');
```

When I try to patch the entity with the array I get this:

```
'valid_from' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
    'time' => '2168-12-02T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
}
```

The column in MySQL is of the type date. (I don't want to use datetime as I don't need the time for calculations)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: my guess would be that your clientside or serverside locale is misconfigured.

Comment: Something like that is my guess too, but I have no idea what to change.

Answer (score 0):

Think your issue is that your locale is misconfigured try one of these methods.

**The default locale can be set in your config/bootstrap.php folder by using the following line:**

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'fr_FR');
```

**Changing the Locale at Runtime**

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

I18n::locale('de_DE');
```